# How to deallocate cursor in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I code on both SQL Server and Oracle.
When I'm coding in SQL Server, I used this:

```
OPEN curUSERS;
CLOSE curUSERS;
DEALLOCATE curUSERS;
```

Now, when I'm coding in Oracle, I used this:

```
OPEN curUSERS;
CLOSE curUSERS;
```

I saw a DEALLOCATE keyword in PL/SQL but when I used this statement

```
DEALLOCATE(curUSERS);
```

It throws an error. How can I do the same thing (deallocation) in PL/SQL?

Comment: If it's a keyword I'd expect the invocation to be similar to OPEN and CLOSE, e.g. `DEALLOCATE curUSERS` without the parentheses. But I've never seen or used this. Could you edit the question and provide a link to the Oracle docs for this? Thanks.

Comment: You have hallucinations ! Oracle PL/SQL doesn't have `deallocate` keyword: [Oracle 11.2 PL/SQL Reserved Words and Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/reservewords.htm). I don't know SQL Server but in Oracle closing/deallocating/cleaning up a cursor is one step operation: `close`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oracle doesn't require to deallocate cursor's memory explicitly. Just `CLOSE(cursor)` is fine.

Comment: This is sligthly misleading. Memory used by an explicitly opened cursor is not released until the cursor is explicitly cleaned (or the session is closed). In Oracle terminology the cleanup phase is _closing_.

Comment: This answer is true. Small addition ([See docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)). You can call `close` to explicitly close a cursor and free its resources. If you don't call `close` explicitly, the cursor will be closed at the end of the block in which it was declared (for cursors declared in program blocks/methods), or at the end of the session (for cursors declared on package level).

Answer (score 0):

Explicit cursors should be avoided whenever possible.  Explicit cursors require more code and are slower because they do not automatically bulk collect.  Cursor FOR loops are simple and fast.

**Sample schema**

```
drop table table1;
create table table1 as select 1 a from dual;
```

**Explicit cursors - more code, worse performance**

```
declare
    v_a number;
    cursor table1_cursor is select a from table1;
begin
    open table1_cursor;
    loop
        fetch table1_cursor into v_a;
        exit when table1_cursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_a);
    end loop;
    close table1_cursor;
end;
/
```

**Cursor for loop - less code, better performance**

```
begin
    for table1_rows in (select a from table1)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(table1_rows.a);    
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: The for loop is still not as efficient as forall with bulk collect. If performance is the ultimate goal, then get rid of loop at first place.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Yes, no loop is better when possible.  The question is only directly about reading data, where the for loop is just as efficient as any explicit bulk collect.  Reading and writing often go together, but in my experience there's usually much more reading than writing, and getting automatic bulk collect on the read is good enough.

Comment: We need to write explicit cursor even with bulk collect; to use limit clause

Comment: @RamDwivedi Cursor for loops also take care of that for you.  They automatically use a limit of 100.

Comment: Yeah but 100 is too less for large data processing. Right?

Comment: @RamDwivedi 100 is fine for any size, both in theory and in [practice](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html).  Bulk collect saves processing time by eliminating switching between SQL and PL/SQL.  A limit of 2 reduces the overhead 50%, 3 reduces it 66%, etc.  By the time the limit gets to 100 there is less than 1% of the overhead left to eliminate.  Even for a large data set, there is almost no advantage in moving from 100 to 100,000,000.